# JavaFX: Why that does not connect between label and textfield with setLabelFor?

Tags: javafx, label, textfield

I have the following code:

```
TextField vSuchenTextfield = new TextField("");
vLblSuchfeld.setMnemonicParsing(true);
vSuchenTextfield.setPromptText("Suchbegriff eingeben");
vLblSuchfeld.setLabelFor(vSuchenTextfield);
```

when I click on the vLblSuchfeld label with the mouse, 
the text field vSuchenTextfield is not activated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the javadoc: *"A Label can act as a label for a different Control or Node. This is used for Mnemonics and Accelerator parsing. This allows setting of the target Node."* There is no indication that mouse interaction with the label has any effect on the target node...

Comment: okay, thanks. I java swing it works! What do I have to do if I want to make the label controllable by keyboard with the aim of activating the associated textfield?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring focus to the textfield when you click on the label, I suggest you implement the following (untested) code:

```
TextField vSuchenTextfield = new TextField("");
vLblSuchfeld.setMnemonicParsing(true);
vSuchenTextfield.setPromptText("Suchbegriff eingeben");
vLblSuchfeld.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    vSuchenTextfield.requestFocus();
});
```

Comment: If it works, you should mark it as the answer. If not, I'll try to edit it a bit to get it to work so it can be used for anyone coming after you. Thanks!